# Geany Plugin Preferences not available on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, plugins, preferences, geany, geany-plugin

i'm new. 
I'm currently using **Ubuntu 14.04** with **Geany** and Gedit, Gedit was good but i had some problem with **Geany**. 
I need to active some **plugins** but when i try to open **Plugins Preferences**, the dialog not showing. no thing showing.
I checked **Enable plugin support** in **Preferences** -> **General** -> **Statup** but nothing happen, the dialog is not showing.
When i try to open Geany from **Terminal** with **sudo geany**. i see the **Plugins Preferences** option was grey
I try to **remove** and **reinstall** Geany but nothing change
I try to **download** from **Geany website** **newest version** and install but same proplem
One time, i reinstall Ubuntu, but same error. Please help me, Thanks you and sorry if my english too bad.

Comment: If you're having trouble configuring Geany, you should try asking on either http://unix.stackexchange.com or http://superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activate your plugins via Tools->Plugin Manager.